# Get list of contacts associated with an opportunity

Tags: opportunity, contact, sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I created a ruby on rails service that emails a list of contacts when an opportunity is closed.

To do this, I am trying to get all contacts associated with the Opportunity that was just closed.

However, I have only successfully been able to get all contacts associated with the Account (on line 26). Can someone please help me make that connection?

```
def self.salesforce_send_close_message
  users = User.where("salesforce_access_token IS NOT NULL AND referral_ask_from_crm = true")
  users.each do |u|
    begin
      SalesforceAuth.refresh_access_token!(u)
      client = Restforce.new(
        oauth_token: u.salesforce_access_token,
        refresh_token: u.salesforce_refresh_token,
        client_id: ENV["SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID"],
        client_secret: ENV["SALESFORCE_SECRET"],
        authentication_callback: Proc.new { |x| Rails.logger.debug x.to_s },
        api_version: '41.0'
      )
      user_info = client.user_info
      opportunities = client.query("select Id, Name, AccountId, IsClosed, IsWon, LastModifiedDate from Opportunity where IsClosed = true AND IsDeleted = false AND LastModifiedDate >= #{1.day.ago.iso8601} AND OwnerId = '#{user_info["user_id"]}'")
      opportunities.each do |o|
        next unless o["AccountId"].present?
        followup = u.salesforce_followups.find_by(external_id: o["Id"])
        next if followup
        new_followup = u.salesforce_followups.create(
          external_id: o["Id"],
          deal_name: o["Name"]
        )
        deal_name = o["Name"]
        contacts = client.query("select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email from Contact where AccountId = '#{o["AccountId"]}' ")
        advocates = contacts.select { |c| c["Email"].present? }.map do |c|
          advocate = u.advocates.find_or_initialize_by(email: c["Email"])
          advocate.first_name = c["FirstName"] unless advocate.first_name.present?
          advocate.last_name = c["LastName"] unless advocate.last_name.present?
          advocate.save
          advocate
        end
        template_type = o["IsWon"] ? 'won' : 'lost'
        delivery_message_template = retrieve_delivery_message_template(u, template_type)
        foo_template = retrieve_foo_template(u, template_type)
        next unless delivery_message_template && foo_template
        bundle = u.bundles.create(
          delivery_message_template: delivery_message_template,
          foo_template: foo_template
        )

        DeliveryMailer.salesforce_end_of_sales_cycle(u, advocates, bundle, deal_name).deliver
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      Honeybadger.notify(
        "Failed salesforce send for user with id #{u.id}",
        context: {
          user: u.attributes,
          message: e.message
        },
        backtrace: e.backtrace
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't speak Ruby, but what you need to be doing to filter Contacts is querying against the [`OpportunityContactRole`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitycontactrole.htm#!) junction object. `OpportunityContactRole` connects Contacts to Opportunities and specifies Roles fulfilled by the Contact.

Where you have

```
contacts = client.query("select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email from Contact where AccountId = '#{o["AccountId"]}' ")
```

you'd want something instead like

```
contacts = client.query("select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email from Contact where Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE OpportunityId = '#{o["Id"]}') ")
```